# Regex to find strings containing substring A but not containing substring B

Tags: regex

I didn't see an exact duplicate of this regex question...

In Visual Studio 2012, I need to find all files with 'using' directives that match a specific name space.

Example:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using      System.Data;
  using System.Diagnostics;
```

I want to find all 'System' (substring A) namespace references EXCEPT those containing 'Collections' (substring B).

The desired results:

```
  using System;
  using      System.Data;
  using System.Diagnostics;
```

Seems like a good place to use a regex.

Comment: Should a string like `using System.Generic.Collections;` pass or fail?

Comment: Is order important? What about `using Aardvark.Collections.Management.System ;`. How about `using` statement with compound words like `using SystemManagementCorp.Collections`?

Comment: Are you using VS find in files (using regex) util?

Comment: For my specific case I was looking for 'using' statements that always contain Substr A and never contain Substr B. Substr B happens to be our company namespace so it will be unique. Jerry and Nicholas-Carey, it should fail (I don't want to see those in the results).   @sln, I did use VS find in files.

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum regex that seems to work:

```
  ^.*System(?!\.Collections).*$
```

Breaking it into parts:

```
  ^                  # from the beginning of the string
  .*                 # match all leading ('using ' in my case)
  System             # match 'System'
  (?!\.Collections)  # don't match strings that contain '.Collections'
  .*$                #match all (.*) to the end of the line ($)
```

This variation:

```
  ^.*[ ]System(?!\.Collections).*$
```

will eliminate

```
  using my.System.Data;
  using mySystem.Diagnostics;
```

[Related question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971738/regex-for-all-strings-not-containing-a-string)

[Related question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

[Rubular: A nice online regex utility](http://rubular.com/)

Caveat: I last played seriously with regex about 20 years ago so I'm a newbie again... hope I got the explanation right.

Comment: So, what did `using` have to do with it? Given the mode is (?-s), your regex matches `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX SystemYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY` Also, [ ] already satisfies the `\b`, so no need to include both (probably just [ ]). If `'using System.something'` are the results you get, then thats all you have. Hey, its a temporary search, no need to be specific anyway.

Comment: It can basically be rewritten as `[ ]System(?!\.Collections)` since full lines display in the output anyway.

Comment: `using` - in the end, nothing.   Yes on the `\b` or `[]` point, only one is needed.  And yes, `[ ]System(?!\.Collections)` works, but because of the substrings returns a bunch of matches that aren't what I'm looking for (although, useful for other reasons).

Comment: Your original regex had `.*` before and after. So, there is absolutely no difference by clipping them out, you get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about

- `(?!...)`. zero-width negative lookahead.
- `(?<!...)`. zero-width negative lookbehind

The regular expression

```
Regex rxFooNotBar = new Regex( @"(?<!bar)Foo(?!Bar)" ) ;
```

will match strings containing "Foo" but not "Bar".

For your specific case — find `using` statements that reference `System` namespaces that don't have 'Collections' as a child namespace, this should do the trick:

```
Regex rxUsingStatements = new Regex( @"^\s*using\s+System\.(?!Collections)[^; \t]*\s*;" ) ;
```

should do you.